# Is it possible to view only "out" cells in iPython Notebook?

Tags: ipython

Sometimes i don't need code and just want to see the report in iPython. Is it possible to view only "out" cells in iPython Notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Install [ipython-notebook-extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Home_3x#usability).  These extensions provide many features, including `runtools`, which allows you to

> Hide or show input (i.e. the source code) of marked code cells
>
> Hide or show output of marked code cells

If you are using ipython3.x, you can install from an ipython notebook via the following:

```
import IPython.html.nbextensions as nb
ext= 'https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/archive/3.x.zip'
nb.install_nbextension(ext)
```

Load `runtools` extension

```
from IPython.html.services.config import ConfigManager
ip = get_ipython()
cm = ConfigManager(parent=ip, profile_dir=ip.profile_dir.location)
cm.update('notebook', {"load_extensions": {"IPython-notebook-extensions-3.x/usability/runtools/main": True}})
```

From a normal notebook, below,
[image] 
you can mark a cell (or all cells) and 
[image]
either view or hide input and output.
[image]